# How to get the body of a 40x response?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

My code is

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
URI uri = URIUtils.createURI(SCHEME, HOST, PORT, path, formatedParams, null);
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
```

When I execute this code and that the response status is `400`, an error is thrown on the last line and I cannot get what should be inside `responseBody`. If I do the same request via a browser (*Chrome*), I can see the response contents.

**I would like to be able to see the response body in my java code.** Response being a 200 or a 400.

In case, the error is

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Bad Request
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:68)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:1070)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:1044)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:1035)
```

Comment: The Bad Request is the server saying that it doesn't like something in your GET. Probably missing something to set in the GET request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like BasicResponseHandler can't handle 400. Maybe try:

```
  HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
  InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
  // TODO Stream to String
```

Comment: Indeed he can't: `If the response code was >= 300, the response body is consumed and an HttpResponseException is thrown.` http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/BasicResponseHandler.html